# percent_rank function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use the percent_rank function in dplyr to divide one of my variables to into 3 separate variables depending on where they fall in the percent rank. I have the dplyr function loaded but the console keeps telling me that it can't find the function.

My code looks like this:

```
 library(dplyr)
 high_val <- percent_rank(df$val1) <- 0.66
```

And then continues on for each variable I want to divide. 0.66 is the percentile for the high value I want to use (66%). Any ideas?

Comment: You are doing double assignments.  isn't this `high_val <- percent_rank(df$val1)`  If you want multiple buckets, use `cut` or `findInterval`  i.e. `df %>% mutate(valgroup = cut(val, c(0.3, 0,6)))`

Comment: I think you should be doing something like `df %>% mutate(Rank = percent_rank(val1))`. Your desired output is unclear.

Comment: I want to take a column of values from a dataframe and split them into groups based off percentiles. My high percentile is 0.66. In the above line of code I'm trying to use percentile_rank to get the values from val1 that are in the high percentile (0.66) to save to a new variable called "high_val" so that I can use it in a table later.

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(val_group = c('low percent', 'high percent')[percent_rank(val1) >= 0.66 + 1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to calculate the rank, filter and pull the values into a vector. Assuming that you want values equal or greater than 0.66:

```
library(dplyr)
high_val <- df %>%
  mutate(Rank = percent_rank(val1)) %>%
  filter(Rank >= 0.66) %>%
  pull(val1)
```